# Limiting access to directory in php

Tags: php, security, server

Is it possible to limit the user control to access the files in server from PHP (**include, require, file_get_contents, etc.**) to specific folder at the run of the first script (**index.php in public_html**) except for the files we allow.

For Example : 
file1.php in : **/var/www/application/models/** folder can be accessed as we allow that file and other files cannot be accessed

By Default only the files of **/var/www/application/user/** can be accessed!

Comment: Have you considered doing this with server user permissions rather than PHP? If you want to do it with PHP, you're going to have to manage those security settings manually based on your authentication system, because PHP will be run by the same server user.

Comment: Simple: do not put those files into the public webroot!

Comment: can we make  server user to be dynamic while accessing file... like one permission for user1 and other for user2?

Comment: @deceze even though it is not in public webroot it can be accessed like this include "../../". I dont want access in this way as well

Comment: Surely you don't give your `apache` user access to files outside of your webroot... _right_?

Comment: what i want to do is... give one of my friend a folder to put php codes and i dont want him to access my files other than his directory unless i allow the file to be accessed by him

Comment: You need [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html)! This is _exactly_ what it was made for this very reason.

Comment: i have mysql based php authentication.......is is possible to allow his scripts to run only after he logs in?? in that suEXEC??